# Looking for a young adult series read in late 80's or early 90's.

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

Looking for a young adult series I found and loved in late 80's or early 90's. I remember it had a sci-fi/fantasy feel to it and was 5-7 books long. I don't remember the plot behind the series, but in one of the books, the ship they are traveling in crashes on a desert planet and they have to send 3 (I think) of the people to get help. One of them says to remember to pack two extra pairs of socks and an extra pair of shoes to prevent blisters. that is all I remember about that book. In another there are large birds that they have to communicate with for some reason and I remember their feathers being mentioned as important. I remember loving the series and sad that it did not continue...

Comment: Perhaps Dig Allen Space Explorer? From the 60s though.